# Move text to bottom of tabs without changing HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, sharepoint-2010

I need to move single lines of text to the bottom of the tabs. When the tab has a single line of text, the text is at the top now. I need to move it down to the bottom and am having trouble, based on the HTML hierarchy, finding CSS that works. The CSS for this can completely change, but this HTML code cannot change. We want the tab to be the width they are now, 122px, and a min-height of 40px. All tabs need to be at least 40px high, but can go higher.

I am using IE9 and SharePoint 2010, so it is dynamic and the IE9 limits the code I can use. Because the tabs aren’t static, I have to treat each tab as if it is going to be one line of text or multiple lines of text. The code needs to work on all the tabs no matter if it is one line, two lines, three lines, etc.

I tried to do this in jQuery, but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/d7a2st79/

```css
.ui-tabs{
    background: none;
    margin-top:25px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px transparent none;


}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    background:rgb(106, 134, 156);
    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;
    /*border-top:1px #b5c3cc solid;*/
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{
border-radius: 0px;
 margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a{
    font-family:"Cabin", Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:rgb(95, 120, 140);
    color:#ffffff;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:1px 0px 7px 0px;
    /*border:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/

    white-space:normal;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;

}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a:active{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}


.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a{
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{
    background:transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
    clear:both;
    border:0px transparent none;
    border-top:2px #cccccc solid;
    /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/

}

.ui-tabs-nav
{
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.ui-tabs ul.ui-widget-header
{
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active
{
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li
{
    border: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    float: none;
    background-color: rgb(106, 134, 156);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a
{
    padding: 7px 0 9px 0;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav
{
    margin-bottom: -2px;
/*  display:table;*/
    border-spacing: 5px 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
/*  width: 100%;*/
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px;
}
/*tabs*/

.tabs .tab-nav .active a {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;    
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position-x: 0px;
background-position-y: 0px;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size:auto;
border-bottom-color: currentColor;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: #ccc;
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color:#ccc;
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: #ccc;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:0px;
color:#1e3069;
margin-bottom:-2px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-bottom: 9px;
}

ol ul
{
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type: none;  
}

.tabs tab-nav a{
    width:120px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
 }
a{

    text-decoration:none;
}

.tabs ul
{
    margin-top:-25px;
    background:transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    border:0px transparent none;
    border-top:2px #cccccc solid;
    /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
    background:rgb(106, 134, 156);

    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;


}

.tabs ul li
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;/*distance between tabs*/
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
}

.tabs ul li a 
{
    font-family:"Cabin", Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:rgb(95, 120, 140);
    color:#ffffff;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:1px 0px 7px 0px;
    border:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    white-space:normal;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;

}


.tabs ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(95, 120, 140); 
    background:white;
}

.tabs ul li.selected a
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #000;
}


.tabs ul li.selected a:hover, .tabs ul li.selected a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.tabs
{
    border: 0px solid #CCC; padding: 0px;
    border-top-color:#AAA;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;


}
.tabs .tabs li a:active{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}
.home .tabs .tab-container{
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image: url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: currentColor;
    border-left-style:none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: currentColor;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    clear: both;
    color:#333;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:100%;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    outline-color:invert;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}

.tabs, .ui-tabs, .ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all
{

    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


/*tabs*/

.tabs .tab-nav .active a {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;    
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-image: none;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color:#ccc;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width:0px;
    color:#1e3069;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

ol ul
{
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-type: none;  
}

.tabs tab-nav a{
    width:120px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}
a{

    text-decoration:none;
}

.tabs ul
{
    margin-top:-25px;
    background:transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    border:0px transparent none;
    border-top:2px #cccccc solid;
    /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
    background:rgb(106, 134, 156);
    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;

}

.tabs ul li
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;/*distance between tabs*/
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
}

.tabs ul li a 
{
    font-family:"Cabin", Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:rgb(95, 120, 140);
    color:#ffffff;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:1px 0px 7px 0px;
    border:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    white-space:normal;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
}


.tabs ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(95, 120, 140); 
    background:white;
}

.tabs ul li.selected a
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #000;
}


.tabs ul li.selected a:hover, .tabs ul li.selected a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.tabs
{
    border: 0px solid #CCC; padding: 0px;
    border-top-color:#AAA;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
}
.tabs .tabs li a:active{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}
.home .tabs .tab-container{
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image: url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: currentColor;
    border-left-style:none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: currentColor;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    clear: both;
    color:#333;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:100%;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    outline-color:invert;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}

.tabs, .ui-tabs, .ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all
{

    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


div.tabs {
    margin-left:-26px;
    /*margin-left:-45px;*/
    width:110%;
    /*width:115%;*/
    }

/* UL for TABS*/


div.ui-tabs ul > li {
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-type:disc;
    list-style:disc;
    line-height:28px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 15px;
    display:list-item;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    }

div.ui-tabs ul ul  {
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style:disc;
    list-style-type:disc;
    line-height:28px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-indent:30px;
    display:list-item;

}

/*Tabs*/
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    text-align:center;
    width:122px;
    border-left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    margin-left:5px;
    /*margin-left:0px;*/
    text-indent:0px;
    line-height:20px;
    border-left-color:silver;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-style:solid;    

    }


div.ui-tabs-panel table{
    margin-left:15px;
    border-right-width:0px;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-right:0px;

}

div.ui-tabs-panel table td{
    padding:0 15px 0 0;

}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{

    border:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-right:75px;
    padding-left:40px;

}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav{
    margin-left:15px;
}
.ui-tabs {
 position: relative;/* position: relative prevents IE scroll bug (element with position: relative inside container with overflow: auto appear as "fixed") */
 padding: .2em;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
 margin: 0;
 padding: .2em .2em 0;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 margin: 1px .2em 0 0;
 border-bottom-width: 0;
 padding: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
 float: left;
 padding: .5em 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading a {
 cursor: text;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, /* first selector in group seems obsolete, but required to overcome bug in Opera applying cursor: text overall if defined elsewhere... */
.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
 display: block;
 border-width: 0;
 padding: 1em 1.4em;
 background: none;
}
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a{
 min-height:40px !important;
```

```html
<div class="tabs contentTabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist"><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabIndex="0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabs-1"><a id="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-1">Initiatives and Services</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-2"><a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-2">12345678912345678</a></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-3"><a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-3">Latest Reports</a></li></ul>
<div aria-hidden="false" aria-expanded="true" id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
​
```

Comment: try removing the float :left , tab height will be adjusted with text size

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't want to change the size of the tabs; I want to keep it at 40px min-height; I just want to move the <a> text to the bottom if it is one line of text. Right now, the one line text is at the top and I want it at the bottom.

Comment: so u want the tab height min 40 px, and the text at the bottom right ?

Comment: place the <a> inside a  <div> ,try position : relative, bottom : 15px, remove line height : 35px

Comment: that's exactly right, that is what I want but I can't change the HTML. The HTML is dynamic not static and the users can change them to fit their needs. There are many pages that have this tab layout. All tabs on the pages are subject to changes, so they could be multiple lines or one line at different times.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer. CSS only. No changes to the HTML. Hope it helps.

Comment: All of the answers given, including yours, work with modern browsers. But I am using IE9 and SharePoint 2010, so I am limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $('.ui-tabs-anchor').each(function(){
        $(this).html('<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
    });
})
```

```css
.ui-tabs{
    background: none;
    margin-top:25px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px transparent none;


}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    background:rgb(106, 134, 156);
    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;
    /*border-top:1px #b5c3cc solid;*/
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{
border-radius: 0px;
 margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a{
    font-family:"Cabin", Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:rgb(95, 120, 140);
    color:#ffffff;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:1px 0px 7px 0px;
    /*border:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/

    white-space:normal;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;

}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a:active{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}


.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a{
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{
    background:transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
    clear:both;
    border:0px transparent none;
    border-top:2px #cccccc solid;
    /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/

}

.ui-tabs-nav
{
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.ui-tabs ul.ui-widget-header
{
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active
{
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li
{
    border: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    float: none;
    background-color: rgb(106, 134, 156);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a
{
    padding: 7px 0 9px 0;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav
{
    margin-bottom: -2px;
/*  display:table;*/
    border-spacing: 5px 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
/*  width: 100%;*/
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px;
}
/*tabs*/

.tabs .tab-nav .active a {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;    
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position-x: 0px;
background-position-y: 0px;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size:auto;
border-bottom-color: currentColor;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: #ccc;
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color:#ccc;
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: #ccc;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:0px;
color:#1e3069;
margin-bottom:-2px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-bottom: 9px;
}

ol ul
{
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type: none;  
}

.tabs tab-nav a{
    width:120px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
 }
a{

    text-decoration:none;
}

.tabs ul
{
    margin-top:-25px;
    background:transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    border:0px transparent none;
    border-top:2px #cccccc solid;
    /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
    background:rgb(106, 134, 156);

    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;


}

.tabs ul li
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;/*distance between tabs*/
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
}

.tabs ul li a 
{
    font-family:"Cabin", Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:rgb(95, 120, 140);
    color:#ffffff;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:1px 0px 7px 0px;
    border:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    white-space:normal;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;

}


.tabs ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(95, 120, 140); 
    background:white;
}

.tabs ul li.selected a
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #000;
}


.tabs ul li.selected a:hover, .tabs ul li.selected a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.tabs
{
    border: 0px solid #CCC; padding: 0px;
    border-top-color:#AAA;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;


}
.tabs .tabs li a:active{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}
.home .tabs .tab-container{
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image: url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: currentColor;
    border-left-style:none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: currentColor;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    clear: both;
    color:#333;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:100%;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    outline-color:invert;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}

.tabs, .ui-tabs, .ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all
{

    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


/*tabs*/

.tabs .tab-nav .active a {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;    
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-image: none;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color:#ccc;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width:0px;
    color:#1e3069;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

ol ul
{
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-type: none;  
}

.tabs tab-nav a{
    width:120px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}
a{

    text-decoration:none;
}

.tabs ul
{
    margin-top:-25px;
    background:transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    border:0px transparent none;
    border-top:2px #cccccc solid;
    /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
    background:rgb(106, 134, 156);
    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;

}

.tabs ul li
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;/*distance between tabs*/
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
}

.tabs ul li a 
{
    font-family:"Cabin", Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:rgb(95, 120, 140);
    color:#ffffff;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:1px 0px 7px 0px;
    border:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    white-space:normal;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
}


.tabs ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: rgb(95, 120, 140); 
    background:white;
}

.tabs ul li.selected a
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: #000;
}


.tabs ul li.selected a:hover, .tabs ul li.selected a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.tabs
{
    border: 0px solid #CCC; padding: 0px;
    border-top-color:#AAA;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
}
.tabs .tabs li a:active{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#1e3069;
}
.home .tabs .tab-container{
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image: url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: currentColor;
    border-left-style:none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: currentColor;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    clear: both;
    color:#333;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:100%;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    outline-color:invert;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}

.tabs, .ui-tabs, .ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all
{

    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


div.tabs {
    margin-left:-26px;
    /*margin-left:-45px;*/
    width:110%;
    /*width:115%;*/
    }

/* UL for TABS*/


div.ui-tabs ul > li {
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-type:disc;
    list-style:disc;
    line-height:28px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 15px;
    display:list-item;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    }

div.ui-tabs ul ul  {
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style:disc;
    list-style-type:disc;
    line-height:28px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-indent:30px;
    display:list-item;

}

/*Tabs*/
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    text-align:center;
    width:122px;
    border-left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    margin-left:5px;
    /*margin-left:0px;*/
    text-indent:0px;
    line-height:20px;
    border-left-color:silver;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-style:solid;    

    }


div.ui-tabs-panel table{
    margin-left:15px;
    border-right-width:0px;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-right:0px;

}

div.ui-tabs-panel table td{
    padding:0 15px 0 0;

}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{

    border:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-right:75px;
    padding-left:40px;

}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav{
    margin-left:15px;
}
.ui-tabs {
 position: relative;/* position: relative prevents IE scroll bug (element with position: relative inside container with overflow: auto appear as "fixed") */
 padding: .2em;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
 margin: 0;
 padding: .2em .2em 0;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 margin: 1px .2em 0 0;
 border-bottom-width: 0;
 padding: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
 float: left;
 padding: .5em 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading a {
 cursor: text;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, /* first selector in group seems obsolete, but required to overcome bug in Opera applying cursor: text overall if defined elsewhere... */
.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
 display: block;
 border-width: 0;
 padding: 1em 1.4em;
 background: none;
}
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a{
    min-height:40px !important;
    position: relative;
}
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a > div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs contentTabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabIndex="0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabs-1">
            <a id="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-1">Initiatives and Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-2">
            <a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-2">Don't input too long text here</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-3">
            <a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-3">Latest Reports</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can wrap text inside `a` by a `div` tag. Then use `position: absolute;`

```
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    position: relateive;
}

div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a > div{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can use Jquery to update your HTML:

```
$(function(){
    $('.ui-tabs-anchor').each(function(){
        $(this).html('<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
    });
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robinhuy/hg9h4ak6/
[image]

Comment: Hi Robin, because the tab is dynamic I can't change the HTML code. It has to be just the CSS or JS. I figured I needed to change the hierarchy of the code if I wanted to accomplish what I want to do. Is there any way to do it without changing the HTML?

Comment: If use only CSS, you can use `display: flex;` but this CSS only work for IE 11. If you can use JS, on document ready loaded just use JS to add span tag to the title of tab.

Comment: For your demo, is there a way to keep the first tab at two lines of text instead of flattening to one line? I want the two lines of text to stay two lines and the one liners to stay one line.

Comment: In my demo, text can be 3 lines but overflow a bit. If text too long, it only display maximum 3 lines.

Comment: At first I uploaded the jQuery code, CSS, and jQuery 2.1.3 library and it flattened the tabs on the SharePoint 2010 site. I don't know why, so I took out jQuery library and just put your jQuery and CSS code. That did it! I was able to set a bottom margin too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using `flexbox` in a minimal way as progressive enhancement then...

```
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  min-height: 40px !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;  
}
```

```css
.ui-tabs {
  background: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px transparent none;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  background: rgb(106, 134, 156);
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 13px;
  /*border-top:1px #b5c3cc solid;*/
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  font-family: "Cabin", Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgb(95, 120, 140);
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 0px 7px 0px;
  /*border:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
  white-space: normal;
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a:active {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1e3069;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1e3069;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a {} .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  background: transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  clear: both;
  border: 0px transparent none;
  border-top: 2px #cccccc solid;
  /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
}
.ui-tabs-nav {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.ui-tabs ul.ui-widget-header {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  border: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  float: none;
  background-color: rgb(106, 134, 156);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  padding: 7px 0 9px 0;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  /*  display:table;*/
  border-spacing: 5px 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  /*  width: 100%;*/
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px;
}
/*tabs*/

.tabs .tab-nav .active a {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  border-bottom-color: currentColor;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-color: #ccc;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  color: #1e3069;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
ol ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.tabs tab-nav a {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs ul {
  margin-top: -25px;
  background: transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  border: 0px transparent none;
  border-top: 2px #cccccc solid;
  /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
  background: rgb(106, 134, 156);
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 13px;
}
.tabs ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  /*distance between tabs*/
  font: normal 12px Verdana;
}
.tabs ul li a {
  font-family: "Cabin", Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgb(95, 120, 140);
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 0px 7px 0px;
  border: 1px #a0aeb9 solid;
  white-space: normal;
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
}
.tabs ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: rgb(95, 120, 140);
  background: white;
}
.tabs ul li.selected a {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
.tabs ul li.selected a:hover,
.tabs ul li.selected a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.tabs {
  border: 0px solid #CCC;
  padding: 0px;
  border-top-color: #AAA;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
}
.tabs .tabs li a:active {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1e3069;
}
.home .tabs .tab-container {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  border-bottom-color: currentColor;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-color: currentColor;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-color: currentColor;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #cccccc;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  clear: both;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  outline-color: invert;
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.tabs,
.ui-tabs,
.ui-widget,
.ui-widget-content,
.ui-corner-all {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
/*tabs*/

.tabs .tab-nav .active a {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: none;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  border-bottom-color: currentColor;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-color: #ccc;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  color: #1e3069;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
ol ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.tabs tab-nav a {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs ul {
  margin-top: -25px;
  background: transparent url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  border: 0px transparent none;
  border-top: 2px #cccccc solid;
  /*border-left:1px #a0aeb9 solid;
    border-right:1px #a0aeb9 solid;*/
  background: rgb(106, 134, 156);
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 13px;
}
.tabs ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  /*distance between tabs*/
  font: normal 12px Verdana;
}
.tabs ul li a {
  font-family: "Cabin", Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgb(95, 120, 140);
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 0px 7px 0px;
  border: 1px #a0aeb9 solid;
  white-space: normal;
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
}
.tabs ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: rgb(95, 120, 140);
  background: white;
}
.tabs ul li.selected a {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
.tabs ul li.selected a:hover,
.tabs ul li.selected a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.tabs {
  border: 0px solid #CCC;
  padding: 0px;
  border-top-color: #AAA;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
}
.tabs .tabs li a:active {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #1e3069;
}
.home .tabs .tab-container {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('/Style%20Library/Images/branding/gradient-background-white.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  border-bottom-color: currentColor;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-color: currentColor;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-color: currentColor;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #cccccc;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  clear: both;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  outline-color: invert;
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.tabs,
.ui-tabs,
.ui-widget,
.ui-widget-content,
.ui-corner-all {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
div.tabs {
  margin-left: -26px;
  /*margin-left:-45px;*/
  width: 110%;
  /*width:115%;*/
}
/* UL for TABS*/

div.ui-tabs ul > li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style: disc;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  display: list-item;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
div.ui-tabs ul ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style: disc;
  list-style-type: disc;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-indent: 30px;
  display: list-item;
}
/*Tabs*/

div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  text-align: center;
  width: 122px;
  border-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  /*margin-left:0px;*/
  text-indent: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-left-color: silver;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
}
div.ui-tabs-panel table {
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-right: 0px;
}
div.ui-tabs-panel table td {
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-right: 75px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.ui-tabs {
  position: relative;
  /* position: relative prevents IE scroll bug (element with position: relative inside container with overflow: auto appear as "fixed") */
  padding: .2em;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .2em .2em 0;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin: 1px .2em 0 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  float: left;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-loading a {
  cursor: text;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a,
/* first selector in group seems obsolete, but required to overcome bug in Opera applying cursor: text overall if defined elsewhere... */

.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  display: block;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.4em;
  background: none;
}
div.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  min-height: 40px !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs contentTabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabIndex="0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabs-1"><a id="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-1">Initiatives and Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-2"><a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-2">12345678912345678</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-3"><a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabIndex="-1" href="#tabs-3">Latest Reports</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div aria-hidden="false" aria-expanded="true" id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
    ​
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code and it works in Dreamweaver, but doesn't work when I applied it to Microsoft SharePoint Desinger to put on the final site. We are using SharePoint 2010 plus we use IE9 and it doesn't seem to recognize flex.